# innerHTML not printing anything

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Im trying some stuff for an exam and I can't make it work. It's really simple and i can't understand why is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercici 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //rep 2 paràmetres d'entrada i els suma
        function suma(a, b) {
            alert(arguments.length);
            //donaria undefined, ja que no existeix el argument amb índex 2, tindria que ser [1]
            alert(arguments[2]);
            //3 + 5 = 8
            return a + b;
        }

        var result = suma(3,5);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<strong>Suma</strong>: 3 + 5 = " + result + "<br>";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know `alert(arguments[2]);` will show undefined.

Comment: The script should be placed after the `div id="result"` element

Comment: In your case when the script is executed the element `result` is not yet added to the dom, that is why the error... else you need to use the `onload` event

Comment: window.onload event will not be available until every element is rendered. Not good if you have many or large imgs or videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is you are calling function before DOM is rendered. So `result` is not available. Move your script after body.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exercici 2</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //rep 2 paràmetres d'entrada i els suma
  function suma(a, b) {
    //3 + 5 = 8
    return a + b;
  }

  var result = suma(3, 5);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<strong>Suma</strong>: 3 + 5 = " + result + "<br>";
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas un onload para que funcione pues llamas el getElement By Id, antes de que exista el elemento y no tiene sentido. Ademas tu salida debe ser un string.

You need a "onload" function for this case, because you declare your getElemetnById before the element, also your output in your function should be a string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //rep 2 paràmetres d'entrada i els suma
    function suma(a, b) {
        //a = argumento 0, b = argumento 1
        return (a + b).toString();
    }
    //estas ejecutando esto, sin antes existir el id="result", por tanto debes esperar
    // aque primero se cree, y luego ejecutar, eso se hace añadiendo esto:

    window.onload = function(){ //espera a que todos los elements html se creen.
            var result = suma(3,5);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<strong>Suma</strong>: 3 + 5 = " + result + "<br>";
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Sums, it is advisable to add `parseInt`, 
this way you can also add `var result = suma('3', 5);` and it will return 8, if you dont have the parseInt and you parse a `string '3'` it will concat it and will return `35`

```
  function suma(a, b) {
    //3 + 5 = 8
    return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  }

  var result = suma(3, 5);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<strong>Suma</strong>: 3 + 5 = " + result + "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the problem is not about printi 35 or 8, the problem is it doesn't print anything!!

Comment: Yup i saw that, but as you said it was mere just something to note.